# How to update a Vector layer with WFS protocol, after updating the filter?

Tags: openlayers-2, wfs

I am using a Vector Layer with WFS protocol to show only a subset of the data. The filter which defines the subset, changes dynamically from the code. How do I refresh the layer, to show only the data that satisfies the new filter?

layer.refresh(); does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your vector layer is called wfslayer, use the the force option on the refresh method like this:

```
wfslayer.refresh({force: true});
```

Comment: This also works for an OpenLayers.Layers.XYZ, let's say after an url-change with xyzLayer.setURL(), then just xyzLayer.redraw({force: true});

Answer (score 3):

you could also do this:

```
var refresh = new OpenLayers.Strategy.Refresh({force: true, active: true});
```

and then as a strategy on the WMS layer :

```
strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed(), refresh],
```

then call this where and when needed:

```
refresh.refresh();
```

**edit**:

If you want to test, try this from your init() (onload property content) or in a document.ready block:

```
  /* Now reload the vector data every 20 seconds */
  setInterval(function () {
        refresh.refresh();
  },20000);
```

It has to show the async requests in the firebug console and under the  tab too, if not your not calling it for some reason.

Comment: I can't get this to work. refresh.refresh() does not cause the layer to refresh. I can't see any request being sent in firebug.

Comment: Where are you calling this from ?  can you show some code in your question?  This comes from a production page so it has to work.   Update your question with the code you have so far and we'll get this to work.

Comment: This worked for me. I needed to force the refresh on the Refresh Strategy itself to make my WFS layers trigger the refresh event and go get new data. Thanks.